# I am using Translation API for language conversion.But i am not able to get translation Accuracy

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, language-translation, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

I am using microsoft translation api for language translation from source Language to English, it is working fine. But i want to have the translation accuracy. any help will be appreciated.
I have gone through the below article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-info-overview

Translation api should return translation accuracy or score.

Comment: Brother can you please help me regard this. i am working on some module of android where i need to translate word with microsoft tranlation api,Please help me brother

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Translator evaluates the quality with the BLEU (bilingual evaluation understudy) standards and our own benchmarks (both automatic and human evaluations).

Depending on multiple variables, such as length and type of text translated, language pairs (source and target), industry lingo, or the domain in which Translator is used, results will vary greatly for any vendor offering a machine translation solution.